# Pandas DataFrame Drop 0.000000 values after .sum()

Tags: python, pandas

How can you drop rows with `0.000000` values from a dataframe?

For instance:

```
PassengerId    0.000000
Survived       0.000000
Pclass         0.000000
Name           0.000000
Sex            0.000000
Age            0.198653
SibSp          0.000000
Parch          0.000000
Ticket         0.000000
Fare           0.000000
Cabin          0.771044
Embarked       0.002245
```

How to drop all columns with 0.000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what the result you exactly want, if you want to have the only columns from the dataframe for which `sum` is not 0, then @BENY's solution is what you are looking for.

If you want to filter out from the result of `sum` that you have in above example in the quesiton, then you can try this:

```py
>>> s = df.sum() # The sum that you have in above example
>>> s[s.ne(0)]

Age         0.198653
Cabin       0.771044
Embarked    0.002245
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
out = df.loc[:,df.sum().ne(0)]
```

Then try with `numpy` `isclose`

```
out = df.loc[:,np.isclose(df.sum(),0)]
```

Comment: I got this: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'ne'